# Why do *nix programs use so many files?

Tags: unix, filesystems

Is there a programmatic advantage to having thousands of files on a volume?

For example, the archive I downloaded for Emacs 22.3 has more than 2,700 files in it. Are those all really necessary? Notepad++, which is comparable in functionality, has a mere 15-30 files in its core, depending on what plugins you use, and it works perfectly well with those.

Of course, the Emacs isn't the only example -- MinGW for C/C++ with MSYS is 8,800 files,  while Visual Studio 2008 -- including the IDE and the C/C++ compilers -- is 12,000 files.

Do I really need that many files in order to be able to use Emacs, or do they provide an advantage to the developers of the original program, or both?

Comment: Emacs and Notepad++ do not compare at all.

Comment: I would argue that, but that would go on a tangent. So another question: what about the MinGW compilers and Visual Studio as a whole? Are those still not comparable either?

Comment: Name a file that you think is unnecessary and we can take a stab at saying why it's there. Clearly (well, ok, apparently not to everyone) there are many _different_ reasons why various files are part of any given distribution.

Comment: "I would argue that" -- from what knowledge base? Since a large part of the emacs distribution consists of individual elisp files each of which is separately loadable and provides a separate bit of functionality, no program consisting of 15-30 files could have comparable functionality.

Comment: @Jim: From the knowledge base that I haven't found anything useful I could do in Emacs that I couldn't do in Notepad++, for C, C++, Java, Scheme, etc, with one notable exception: Playing tetris. Other than that, though, let's not get into that discussion, it's a digression.

Comment: @Jim: I don't *know* which files are necessary and which ones aren't, but now that you mention it, [I took a look](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-23.2-bin-i386.zip), and just as examples of suspiciously useless-looking files, I would cite: `etc\HELLO`, `etc\INTERVIEW`, `etc\JOKES`, `etc\MH-E-NEWS`, `etc\WHY-FREE`, etc... however, I don't mean this to turn into a rant; I really want to know if there was a programmatic advantage to having those files, but right now it's beyond me.

Comment: I've cleaned up the argumentative tone and reopened, assuming you want a genuine answer to your question, and this isn't just a rant. Also, I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss @Starkey's comment; it is probably the right answer to your question.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm a vi advocate myself, but I'd still say that it would be more fair to compare the code base of Emacs with Visual Studio or Eclipse or Linux for that matter than Notepad++. That's apples and oranges.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks so much. I couldn't quite figure out what was different about it (although I did notice something was different) but when I looked at the edits, they were quite helpful. :)

Comment: @Judge: I guess another way to look at it is the number of files versus how big the files are. I've noticed that *nix programs usually have a lot of small files, while Windows programs have fewer, bigger files. So I'm not really comparing the programs, but I'm comparing why they make so many files. Hope that clarifies what I meant.

Comment: @Roberts Nice edit. Exactly why we should be able to vote on edits :)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but... These are terrible examples. Neither Emacs/Notepad++ nor VS/MinGW are directly comparable.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't believe that the question of whether to include those etc files provides a "programmatic advantage" is either a serious or an appropriate one. If you don't need those historic files, feel free to delete them, but not if your going to propagate the source -- see the GNU license. And if you don't want to download them in the first place, don't use emacs.

Comment: @Mehrdad The question of whether emacs provides functionality that Notepad++ doesn't is not a digression, it's critical to your argument. And the fact that _you_ couldn't find anything useful in emacs beyond what Notepad++ gives you is irrelevant as long as you are not the only person on the planet.

Comment: @Jim: If you'd really like, I could open up a question on Emacs vs. Notepad++, but I have a feeling that that would definitely be closed as "subjective and argumentative" -- even *I* might vote for that. So unless you'd like to start that discussion and see how it goes (in which case I'd be more than happy to discuss the advantages/disadvantages), let's not digress here. (Trust me, I have a lot to say about this topic, but I don't think this is the best/time place for it.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Again, it's not a digression, it's critical to your argument. And it doesn't matter how much you have to say about a topic with which you are clearly unfamiliar.

Comment: @Jim: If you really want to discuss it, open a new topic, and I'll discuss it on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples you give ended up this way by design.

- Emacs: Emacs is a lisp script interpreter. Its GUI primitives are clearly intended to support text editing applications, but the underlying language and the core libraries are general purpose. The decision to go with scripts instead of plugins makes it very easy to hack, customize and expand the capabilities of Emacs. Countless developers and engineers have used Emacs to add syntax highlighting for proprietary languages, code completion, as well as input forms. In this light, you can think of Emacs as a forerunner for macro and scripting features of modern office productivity packages.
- IDE and C/C++ compilers: C/C++ applications are compiled and linked by combining source code with static and dynamic libraries. A modern C/C++ compiler comes with a wide array of libraries, of which most typical applications would only use a fraction. Separating and organizing this content in separate files helps manage the large volume of contents for both the vendor and the users.

Comment: Ah... the explanations make a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Files are a simple, natural, logical unit that can be easily handled in code.  File systems are designed to effortlessly handle thousands of them.  Saying that Emacs has too many files in it suggests a problem that might not actually exist.